# How to access variables made in __init_subclass__ from __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, python-magic

Here is sample code:

```
from abc import *


class weightlayer(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.order = cls.count
        cls.count += 1

    @abstractmethod
    def init_weight(self):
        pass


class A_layer(weightlayer):
    def init_weight(self):
        pass


class B_layer(weightlayer):
    def init_weight(self):
        pass
```

I already searched it many times but I can't find the solution.
My idea doesn't work because `__ init __` function doesn't have the `cls` parameter.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` is an instance method, so you have to get to the actual class via the instance `self`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.order = self.__class__.count
    self.__class__.count += 1

a1 = A_layer()
A_layer.count
# 1
a1.order
# 0
a2 = A_layer()
A_layer.count
# 2
a2.order
# 1
B_layer.count
# 0
```